# -nodes function during CSR creation with OpenSSL

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, pki, csr

This is a typical command to create CSR and private key with OpenSSL.

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout myserver.key -out server.csr
```

What is the function of `-nodes` in the command line? I google but couldn't find my answer. Perhaps anyone here could explain the function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if this option is specified then if a private key is created it will not be encrypted. As in "No DES", not "nodes".

Comment: oh. I think I encountered this. Is this why apache asking for my private key  password during httpd restart?

Comment: The pass phrase?

Comment: yes. Nevermind. I think you solved it.